# Reputation Retained After Deleting Answer on Migrated Question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, migration, deleted-answers

A couple of years ago, I answered [a question (*)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105473/im-replacing-my-outlets-and-i-have-too-many-hot-neutral-wires-what-do-i-do) on EE.SE that was subsequently migrated to Home Improvement. Prior to migration my answer had IIRC about 5 upvotes.

**I didn't have an account on Home Improvement at the time of migration**. But at a later date I joined the community and at that point the backdated reputation that was transferred over was linked to my account.

For various reasons I ended up deleting the answer on Home Improvement.

I've not been particularly active on Home Improvement, so it has taken a while to notice that despite the fact that I deleted the answer, I still appear to [have the reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/69655/tom-carpenter?tab=reputation) from it.

I was under the impression that any reputation from an answer is lost when it is deleted. However this does not appear to have happened.

Is this a bug in the system? or am I missing something?

---

(*) <s>I've tried looking for the question itself, but can't remember what it was called - I know only that I deleted my answer on Sept 20th 2017 as I ended up with the disciplined badge on Home Improvement.</s> Found it.

Comment: Worked out more about the timeline of events from the reputation vs time tab on my profile. I wonder if it is releated to not having had an account on the destination stack at the point of migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design.

When posts are greater than sixty days old at the time of deletion, if they have a high enough score (+3), the user retains the reputation earned from that post.

So, since the [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105473/im-replacing-my-outlets-and-i-have-too-many-hot-neutral-wires-what-do-i-do/105474#105474) had a score of +3 and was written on Dec 31, 2016 and not deleted until September 20, 2017, you get to keep the rep!

Enjoy!